# D3.js / viz.js - set proper drawing order

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've started to create custom chart based on vizJS examples.

My current issue is that I cannot simply render the left & right column of visual with the proper order (draw rows starting from the biggest number - descending order).

There is vizJS sortPrimary & sortSecondary method which can be used for `d.key`, but how to sort `d.value` via using those mentioned sort methods?

Code attached here:
http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/03bff9eb85bb1f25e0bb669187a01c77